# Does Caliburn.Micro for Xamarin.Forms have the concept of automatically selecting a matching view like in WPF?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, caliburn.micro

One of the best things, for me at least, is that when using Caliburn.Micro for WPF it will automatically select the correct view based on the view model used.

So for example if I have a list containing `CarViewModel` objects it will automatically create a data template that uses `CarView` for rendering each item in the list.

Now since we don't have the `"x:Name"` concept in `Xamarin.Forms` does this mean this functionality does not exist for Caliburn in `Xamarin.Forms`?

I'm asking here since there is almost no documentation available for `Caliburn.Micro` + Xamarin.Forms at this time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question :) It was mentioned in the Caliburn 3.0 announcement, what you do is simply this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Features}" HasUnevenRows="True">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <ContentView cm:View.Model="{Binding}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

So this part: `cm:View.Model="{Binding}"` together with a `<ContentView/>` simply needs to be added, works great!